# How to get value from Cursor execution result Python

Tags: python, sqlite, cursor

I have a sqllite database in which the field dad_mmsi is created without a type:

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AIS_anoniem
             (dad_mmsi, dad_navstatus......)'''')
```

when i fetch the top result;

```
c.execute('SELECT DISTINCT dad_mmsi FROM AIS')
print c.fetchall()[0]
```

it prints:

```
(u'456000001',)
```

which is not the same as what i put in, because it is converted to a tuple.

EDIT: since it is a tuple i need to access the index of the value i want:

```
 print c.fetchall()[0][0] == '456000001'
```

gives me:

```
 'true'
```

Comment: `(u'456000001',)` is the first row returned, your value is not converted to a tuple, that is the result row you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

`fetchall` returns a list of rows, and each row is a list (tuple) of columns.
So this is correct.

Your query with `DISTINCT` does not return the top result, it returns all unique values.
To return only the first result, use

```
SELECT dad_mmsi FROM AIS LIMIT 1
```

(but you should add an `ORDER BY` clause to control which record you get).

To return only one row, use not `fetchall` but `fetchone`.